# basic string comparison for russian character in php

Tags: php, string, internationalization, comparison

How can a basic string comparison be performed on russian (cyrillic) characters?

Comment: Any chance you can provide some test data, and any methods you have tried thusfar? We're here to help, but you should try and help yourself first, and give us enough material to try and assist you with working out a solution.

Comment: Yeah, you should really start adding more context to your questions. This is not enough information by far to solve whatever problem you are facing.

Comment: Im sorry for the incomplete question. The thing is I am able to display a query which have russian characters, but the same query if executed through php enters meaningless symbols into the database  `INSERT INTO data(name) VALUES('Компа'),('ОО "Гарм"'),('Нефтая компания "ЛУКйл"')` The same query if copy pasted into the db, the values are correctly entered. If this query is executed from php enters meaningless symbols –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//connect to the db

//make sure you set the charset to utf8 before you insert.
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
```